# Insert Missing Months rows in the dataframe in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
Input:-

ID month   Name
A1 2017.01 A
A1 2017.02 B
A1 2017.04 C
A2 2017.02 A
A2 2017.03 D
A2 2017.05 C

Output:-

ID month   Name
A1 2017.01 A
A1 2017.02 B
A1 2017.03 B
A1 2017.04 C
A2 2017.02 A
A2 2017.03 D
A2 2017.04 D
A2 2017.05 C
```

I require to get the missing months in the sequence and the value of the month preceding it and which is present in the input list. **Consider example of ID "A1". "A1" has months 1,2,4 and has missing month 3. So i need to add the row with value "A1" as ID, month as "2017.03" and Name as "B". Please note the "Name" column should get its value from the row immediately above it that is present in the input.**

How do I achieve this in pandas, or by any other method in python.

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's try this with @EFT's suggestion:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.month.astype(str),format='%Y.%m')
df_out = df.set_index('Date').groupby('ID').resample('MS').asfreq().ffill().reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
df_out = df_out.reset_index()
df_out['month'] = df_out.Date.dt.strftime('%Y.%m')
df_out = df_out.drop('Date',axis=1)
print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
   ID    month Name
0  A1  2017.01    A
1  A1  2017.02    B
2  A1  2017.03    B
3  A1  2017.04    C
4  A2  2017.02    A
5  A2  2017.03    D
6  A2  2017.04    D
7  A2  2017.05    C
```

Comment: Can't you do this without `apply`? Just `df.set_index('Date').groupby(...`?

Comment: This is genius, quick question though how does the df know to forward fill the name category only?

Comment: @Tony It doesn't, it ffills everything, then I go back and copy over Month with the correct string.

Comment: Just word of caution: If e.g. the first value for ID A2 (2017.02) is missing, it is filled by last value from ID A1 (2017.04). I think this is desired behavior in this setting, but might not usually be.

Answer (score 0):

There was a question in the comments about how df knows which column to ffill, and I just decided to go through it and post it here, maybe someone finds it useful (or I use it as a reference for myself):

```
mytest = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['A1', 'A1', 'A1', 'A2', 'A2', 'A2'], 'month': ['2017.01', '2017.02', '2017.04', '2017.02', '2017.03', '2017.05'], 'Name':['A','B','C','A','D','C']})
mytest.month = pd.to_datetime(mytest.month)
mytest=mytest.set_index('month').groupby(['ID'])
mytest = mytest.resample('MS').asfreq()['Name']
mytest = pd.DataFrame(pd.DataFrame(mytest).to_records())
mytest.Name = mytest.Name.ffill()
mytest
```

Obviously outputs a very similar thing, I just have not formatted months back to the original format.

```
    ID  month   Name
0   A1  2017-01-01  A
1   A1  2017-02-01  B
2   A1  2017-03-01  B
3   A1  2017-04-01  C
4   A2  2017-02-01  A
5   A2  2017-03-01  D
6   A2  2017-04-01  D
7   A2  2017-05-01  C
```